# TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series' While trying to sort DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got the error when I use the following code:

```py
df=df.sort_values(by=['name', 'ID'])
```

I tried also :

```py
df=df.sort_values(by=['name', 'ID']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The error is:

```py
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'
```

FYI : the dataframe is 21000 rows × 19 columns

Comment: kindly share tour data? how it looks like name & Id and its type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occured because there is different data types in the same columns.

I discovered that values in ID column should be 'np.float64', however some of them are in another type.

The dataset is a result of a `merge` between two dataframes, I think that `merge` is the main source of the problem.

I solved the issue by:

I created a new boolean column where `True` means the 'ID' columns has 'np.float64' and `False` otherwise.

```py
# Create a column showing 'True' if 'ID' has right datatype

df['type_ID']=[type(df['ID'][i])==np.float64 for i in range(len(df))]

# Keep only good values in dataframe

df=df[df['type_ID']==1]

# Drop the additional column

del df['type_ID']
```

Now I sorted values without any issue.